# ModalViewController does not fire WillRotate method

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios

A have an application that has a controller and after swipe it shows another controller as a modal dialog. This showing I do with calling PresentModalViewController(myControl, true). When I have four modal dialogs opened (application maximum) the last one does not fire WillRotate method. Simply if I put a breakpoint it is not hit and the code I have in this method Override is not being processed.

Are there any count limits for showing modal dialogs?

Comment: Maybe a different concept might help you. I'm not sure if it is a good idea to show a modal view on top of another modal view - on desktops it is quite common but no on iOS. Maybe show a UINavigationController inside your modal view instead of stacking modals on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know if there is a count limit for showing modal dialogs but I can provide an alternative solution that may help you get around this problem for the time being.

In your last modal view, you could subscribe to the `OrientationDidChange` notifications:

```
NSNotification.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIDevice.OrientationDidChangeNotification, HandleDeviceRotated);
```

where `HandleDeviceRotated` is a delegate as follows:

```
void HandleDeviceRotates(NSNotification notification)
{
 // Handle any code you'd like when device rotated.
}
```

Unfortunately this will take place after the device has rotated.